# Paste multiple of text in one single cell per row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm receiving some alerts in telegram in the following format

Pinnacle drop value:  22,35%  in last 3 min 
Soccer, Norway - 3rd Division Group 4 
Pors Grenland - Sarpsborg 08 2 
Full time, Asian Handicap -2.0 
· home:  2,13 → 1,65 ↓↓↓
· away:  1,65 → 2,12 
Starts in 44 minutes!

I would like to copy dozens similar alerts at once , and paste them to excel, **one cell per alert** , so I can split them by Delimiter.

Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Copy/paste? What have you tried? What is the actual problem here?

Comment: Hey @cybernetic.nomad , let me show you an example.

[imgur](https://i.imgur.com/d6PXWiX.png)

Comment: Is input data always spread in 7 cells (rows) or it could be more or less as well? Does your version of Excel have TEXTJOIN Function available?

Comment: Use row autoheight from context menu

Answer (score 0):

Mark data (whole rows)

[image]

Click Home-->Fill-->Justify

[image]

Then choose a row width as you like and/or use "Wrap Text"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [TEXTJOIN function](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/textjoin-function-excel-merge-text-multiple-cells/) with a carriage return delimiter.

=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:A6)

Answer (score 0):

You can double click the cell and paste the value is the cell directly.